# How to recognise that the existing contact is new or edited one?

Tags: ios7, contacts

I want to save all the contacts from device with status (like new or edited)in local DB and upload to server . The issue is, if user edit/modify the contact in device, then how can i detect the user has modified the particular contact.

Anybody knows, please share!

Thanks in advance!